# How to save contacts locally on iPhone

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, contacts

Is it possible to save contacts (selectively, eventually) locally on an iPhone, without them being synced to iCloud? (A.k.a. the “*All on My Mac*” option present on the Mac.) And if yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off iCloud for contacts in Settings → iCloud, Contacts. Select "Keep on my iPhone" when asked about previously synced contacts.